# Move Dropbox Smart Synced Files/Folders using Python

Tags: python, dropbox, shutil

If you set Dropbox Smart Sync to online-only for a folder or file, you can still see the file or folder on your computer, but it’s just a placeholder.

I can manually move or copy the files as normal. But the problem is when I use Python to move the files (still within Dropbox), it will have to wait for the files to finish downloading and then move.

I'm using "move" from shutil.

Is there any other way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Dropbox API to issue the commands to the Dropbox servers directly, instead of to your local filesystem:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers

There's an official Dropbox Python SDK here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python

You can use that to copy and move files (among other operations):

- copy: https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_copy_v2
- move: https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_move_v2